# How to add new column in to partition by clause in Hive External Table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have external Hive Table which is filled by spark job and partitioned by(event_date date) now I have modified the spark code and added one extra column 'country'.In earlier written data country column will have null values as it is newly added. now I want to Alter 'partitioned by' clause as partition by(event_date date,country string) how can I achieve this.Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to alter the partition using below commnad-

```
ALTER TABLE table_name PARTITION part_spec SET LOCATION path

part_spec:
    : (part_col_name1=val1, part_col_name2=val2, ...)
```

Try this [databricks spark-sql language manual for alter command](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/alter-table-partitions.html)